# Convert a decimal number to hex

Tags: c, hex, rgb

I need a function rbg() to convert a color specified in decimal to hex.

The color is 2byte long and is coded as 5:6:5.

I already developed a dec_to_hex function:

```
void decimal_hex(int n, char hex[]) /* Function to convert decimal to hexadecimal. */
{
        int i=0,rem;
        while (n!=0)
        {
                rem=n%16;
                switch(rem)
                {
                case 10:
                        hex[i]='A';
                        break;
                case 11:
                        hex[i]='B';
                        break;
                case 12:
                        hex[i]='C';
                        break;
                case 13:
                        hex[i]='D';
                        break;
                case 14:
                        hex[i]='E';
                        break;
                case 15:
                        hex[i]='F';
                        break;
                default:
                        hex[i]=rem+'0';
                        break;
                }
                ++i;
                n/=16;
        }
        hex[i]='\0';
        strrev(hex);   /* Reverse string */
}
```

But now I need to merge this three values for R G AND B

I need something like

```
int rbg (int r, int g, int b){}
```

but I cant figure out how to merge the 3 conversions.

Thanks in advance

Regards

---

```
string ConvertRGBtoHex(int r, int g, int B) {
    int rgbNum = ((r & 0xff) << 16)
                | ((g & 0xff) << 8)
                | (b & 0xff);

    return ConvertRGBtoHex(rgbNum);
}
```

I think this might work but I'm having an issue and my compiler is not recognizing strings.

> expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**atritbute**' before 'convertRBGtoHex

What the heck?

Comment: In what programming language? Also, computers store numbers in binary; what are you asking?

Comment: How are the 16bits(2byte) of color organized?

Comment: It's C.

As I mentioned its a 5:6:5 byte. 

5 bits for RED, 6 bits for green, 5 bits for blue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using your original function as a guide, this should work:

```
void ConvertRGBtoHex (int r, int g, int b, char* out) {
    uint16_t rgbNum = ((r & 0x1f) << 11) |
                      ((g & 0x3f) << 5)  |
                       (b & 0x1f);

    decimal_hex (rgbNum, out);
}
```

#### A white pixel would therefore be:

```
char str [5];
str [4] = '\0';

ConvertRGBtoHex (31, 63, 31, str);

printf ("Color: %s\n", str);
```

#### Output:

```
"Color: FFFF"
```

Comment: A white pixel is given as 255,255,255 :\

Comment: @user2074085: No it's not. That's 24-bit color. In 16-bit color, when encoded 5:6:5, a white pixel is 31,63,31.